# Retrieve LinkedIn Profile Picture Using JavaScript with REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, oauth, linkedin-api, restful-authentication

I am currently implementing a LinkedIn authorization and sign in feature on my web application and am using the linkedin JavaScript Developer sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: YOUR_API_KEY_HERE
    authorize: true
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    // Handle the successful return from the API call
    function onSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    // Handle an error response from the API call
    function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
    function getProfileData() {
        IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
    }

</script>
```

This segment of code returns the first name, last name, headline (description of job title), and id using the raw() method within the getProfileData() method.

I am now trying to get the users profile picture as well to use on my application and cannot figure out how to do so with the code I already have.  The linkedIn developer site gives the following example of how to do so with the REST api:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(picture-url)?format=json
```

I have never used the REST API so I cannot figure out how to implement this code into the existing segment that I have.  How could i make a request to this REST API code with my existing JS code so that the prorgam can get both text data and the users image?

Comment: make a request to https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(picture-url)?format=json and it should return a result containing a json file with the picture

Comment: How would a request to this API be written?  I understand that it does need to be in the form of a request i just dont know the JS code to do it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_http.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to retrieve the profile image, you don't need it in the JSON format. Just use

```
function onSuccess(data) {
     String imageUrl = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/"+data.id+"/picture-url";
     //i.e. $("img").attr("src",imageUrl);
}
```

Replace {user-id} with the actual user id. You can access it once you pass the authorization scheme.